# AngularJS Phot Sphere Viewer Plugin does not work on smartphone

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, 360-panorama-viewer

I am using this [example](https://www.bram.us/2016/02/18/javascript-photo-sphere-viewer/), to create an application to dispaly 360 photos on my smartphone, using Ionic.
On the browser, it works well. but when I run it on the phone, I get this error:

```
ionic.bundle.js:26794 TypeError: b is not a function
```

It is not even linked to my code, but to the `photo-sphere-viewer.min.js` file.

Anyone knows the answer to this problem? Thank you.